# Django admin inlines on default list page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a table that only has a handful of entries in it, and it'd be nice if I could use inlines for their list instead of forcing staff to click through to the edit page each time.

That is, when someone clicks on the link that ordinarily gives a list of the model objects, they should instead see the model objects displayed inline.

I tried something like this, but unsurprisingly it gives an error because there's no foreign key:

```
class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline): 
    model = MyModel               

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = [MyModelInline,]    

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work as you've described you'll need an "editor" model to be a parent for the data. All the rows you want to display should have a foreign key to a single 'editor' model object. So, in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Editor(models.Model):
    pass

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Field added for demonstration
    # ... add any other fields you like ...
    editor = models.ForeignKey(Editor)
```

And in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Test.models import Editor, MyModel

class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyModel

class EditorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyModelInline,]
admin.site.register(Editor, EditorAdmin)
```

Some other things to consider:

When you make a new MyModel() object programmatically you must always set the foreign key to point to the editor. There should only be one instance of the editor for this to work as you've described. When using the admin interface, this foreign key should be set automatically by using the admin page for the editor object. I would suggest restricting creation and deletion of editor objects for everyone except yourself in production. If someone deletes the editor object then all MyModel objects disappear as well.

---

Alternative options:

1) If the edits the admin staff is doing are simple then I would recommend [implementing "actions"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) instead.

2) There's also the possibility of [overriding the admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). I personally like this option less because every time Django is updated I have to check that my changes aren't interfering with new features. However, sometimes this is the only way to do some more advanced things in the admin interface. I've done this in my own project, but like to keep the changes minimal.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this add an unnecessary column to MyModel? (There's also the unnecessary Editor table, but that one's more acceptable since it's pretty small.)

Comment: I added the 'name' field for demonstrative purposes. You don't need it in your code. I just wanted to put something in the 'MyModel' class to make sure the test code worked.